# Application Request Routing giving 502.3 error as bad gateway or proxy server

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-farm, arr

I have just set up a web farm with Application Request Routing on IIS 8.5, with Load Balance connecting to two servers. The static page HelloWorld.html and the first login page looks fine. However when the submit button is hit, whenever a code behind is involved it takes a long time to load. I've modified the timeout value from 30s to 300s, then it loads for a few minutes and gave me a

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.

I've enabled trace log but not sure where can I find the exact problem. In the summary it's showing

> MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
>
> ModuleName ApplicationRequestRouting
>
> Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
>
> HttpStatus 502
>
> HttpReason Bad Gateway
>
> HttpSubStatus 3
>
> ErrorCode 2147954430

---

> SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_DESCRIPTION
>
> ErrorDescription The connection with the server was terminated
>   abnormally

---

Anyone had similar experience and is able to give me a hint?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730485/how-can-i-make-arr-work-with-ssl-offloading-disabled-502-3-bad-gateway/43226649#43226649, this may help